# How is FC HBA card compatibility on Ubuntu? [Solved]

Tags: ubuntu, fibre-channel, hba

I have a server running on Ubuntu 16.04, and need to connect this server to a SAN storage via FC.

I wonder which kind of HBA FC card does Ubuntu support? For example, this card is suggested by a local supplier, but Ubuntu is not in supported list:
https://lenovopress.com/tips0882-brocade-16gb-fc-hba

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: 
This card work flawlessly on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The supplier linked a withdrawn product (part number 81Y1675) whose support stops at RHEL 6? If either they intended that to be a generic example, or to meet a specific requirement of yours, they should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

If by support you want to call up the vendor and have a reasonable chance of them helping you, use a OS distro from the supported list. Good support will go above and beyond, but you cannot rely on that.

Its Linux, so the same drivers are in (or could be added to) Ubuntu. However, read the documentation of any management tools. If the firmware flash utility is only delivered as an RPM, you might need to get creative in installing it.